# Why is my button not showing up in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making buttons on my start screen, but they won't show up. I made a button class with everything I need for the button. My bet is that something is wrong with the draw function in my class. Does anyone know how to fix this? If there are any other errors, please let me know. Thank you!

```py
class Button(object):
    def __init__(self, text, text_size, text_color, x, y, width, height, ic, ac):

        self.text = text
        self.text_size = text_size
        self.text_color = text_color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.ic = ic
        self.ac = ac

        self.inactive_button = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.inactive_button.fill(ic)

        self.active_button = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.active_button.fill(ac)

        self.button_rect = self.inactive_button
        self.rect = self.button_rect.get_rect()

        font_name = pygame.font.match_font('arial')
        font = pygame.font.Font(font_name, text_size)
        font_text = font.render(text, True, text_color)
        text_rect = font_text.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

        self.inactive_button.blit(font_text, text_rect)
        self.active_button.blit(font_text, text_rect)

        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)

        self.hovered = False
        # self.clicked = False

    def update(self):

        if self.hovered:
            self.button_rect = self.active_button
        else:
            self.button_rect = self.inactive_button

    def draw(self, screen):

        screen.blit(self.button_rect, self.rect)

    def handle_event(self, event, command=None):

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            self.hovered = self.rect.collide_rect(mouse, self.rect)
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if command == 'play' and command is not None:
                    game_loop()
                elif command == 'quit' and command is not None:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
                elif command == 'instructions' and command is not None:
                    instructions()
                elif command == 'credits' and command is not None:
                    credits()
                elif command == 'back' and command is not None:
                    start_screen()


def start_screen():

    start = True

    while start:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for events in pygame.event.get():
            if events.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            Button("Play", 55, WHITE, 180, 285, 120, 60, BLUE, LIGHT_BLUE)
            Button("Quit", 30, BLUE, 202, 450, 80, 40, WHITE, GRAY)
            Button("Credits", 35, BLACK, 310, 45, 140, 30, WHITE, GRAY)
            Button("Instructions", 30, BLACK, 20, 45, 140, 30, WHITE, GRAY)

start_screen()
```

Comment: it works different then function in your previouse question. You have to create instances before `while True` - `b1 = Button()` and inside `for event` use `b1.handle_event(events)` to check if button was clicked, and after `for event` use `b1.draw()` to draw it (after you clear scren, and before `display.flip()`)

Comment: Now the buttons are showing up, but self.hovered = self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos) isn't making the button "hover"

Comment: Is the event.pos not correct?

Comment: no - problem is that you don't run `button.update()`

Comment: Where should I put that?

Comment: see new code in my answer

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't see that

Comment: I added this later. The same organization of code you can use in all mainloops - for start screen, game, options screen, exit screen,

Comment: How do I give the mouse a rect for the self.rect.collide_rect?

Comment: you don't need rect - mouse is point so you need `self.rect.collidepoint(mouse)`

Comment: Sorry, that was an older comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works different then function in your previouse question.

You have to create instances before `while True` and inside `for event` use `b1.handle_event(events)` to check if button was clicked, and after `for event` use `b1.draw()` to draw it (after you clear screen, and before display.flip())

```
def start_screen():

    start = True

    b1 = Button("Play", 55, WHITE, 180, 285, 120, 60, BLUE, LIGHT_BLUE)
    b2 = Button("Quit", 30, BLUE, 202, 450, 80, 40, WHITE, GRAY)
    b3 = Button("Credits", 35, BLACK, 310, 45, 140, 30, WHITE, GRAY)
    b4 = Button("Instructions", 30, BLACK, 20, 45, 140, 30, WHITE, GRAY)

    while start:

        clock.tick(FPS)

        # - events -

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            b1.handle_event(event)
            b2.handle_event(event)
            b3.handle_event(event)
            b4.handle_event(event)

        # - updates (without draws) - 

        b1.update()
        b2.update()
        b3.update()
        b4.update()

        # - draws (without updates) -

        screen.fill((0,0,0))

        b1.draw(screen)
        b2.draw(screen)
        b3.draw(screen)
        b4.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()
```

---

**EDIT:**

You have wrong indentions and you don't check if you click on hovered button so one click may press all butttons at once.

```
def handle_event(self, event, command=None):

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
        self.hovered = self.rect.collide_rect(mouse, self.rect)

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if self.hovered:
            if command == 'play' and command is not None:
                game_loop()
            elif command == 'quit' and command is not None:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            elif command == 'instructions' and command is not None:
                instructions()
            elif command == 'credits' and command is not None:
                credits()
            elif command == 'back' and command is not None:
                start_screen()
```

but to make button more universal - you could assign function's name instead strings

```
def handle_event(self, event, command=None):

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
        self.hovered = self.rect.collide_rect(mouse, self.rect)

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if self.hovered and command is not noen:
            command()
```

or even put function name in `__init__`

Comment: In handle event, there is an error saying: "    self.hovered = self.rect.collide_rect(mouse, self.rect)
AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'collide_rect'"

Comment: that true - `Rect` doesn't have `collide_rect` but `colliderect` - but mouse position is point so you have to check `self.rect.collidepoint(mouse)` - and you don't need second argument `self.rect` because it compares with `self.rect` which you have in `self.rect.collidepoint` (before `.collidepoint`)

Comment: The hovering works now, but the commands don't. Nothing happens when I click the buttons

Comment: check `EDIT` in answer - you had wrong indention in line `if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:` so it can be executed only when `event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:` but `event` can't have two types at the same time. When type is `MOUSEMOTION` then it can't be `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`

Comment: then put `print()` with message to check if this part of code is executed. You can also display values in variables.

Comment: Oops sorry, I just had to put an action in the update. Sorry about that

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with all my questions. It's so cool how you know so much.

Comment: BTW: on Github I have many examples from my answers on Stackoverflow: [PyGame](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame), and other modules in [Python](https://github.com/furas/python-examples)

Comment: Alright I will definitely look for those in case I need them